# How to Post data from external HTML form to Eloqua Form using cURL

Tags: php, rest, curl, eloqua

I want to post data from an external HTML form to a simple form created in Eloqua, using cURL method. I tried to follow [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-develop/Developers/GettingStarted/APIRequests/curl-requests.htm) but I am not able to post data to Eloqua.

When I try from command line (Windows) -

> curl --user "usercreds" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data "{"testfirstname":"abc","testlastname":"def","singleCheckbox":1}" https://secure.p0{POD Number}.eloqua.com/api/REST/1.0/data/form/{formid}

I get below error:

> *[{"type":"ObjectValidationError","property":"fieldValues","requirement":{"type":"NoDuplicatesRequirement"},"value":""}]*

When I try from PHP, as mentioned here https://www.eehelp.com/question/using-curl-to-repost-to-eloqua-data/
or https://github.com/fredsakr/eloqua-php-request the `curl` returns HTTP code 0.

This is a simple form created in Eloqua without any validations.
I do not know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This usually has to do with the form in Eloqua being misconfigured (ensure the Key Field Mapping is set), or you are missing some required fields that must be passed in your post request. The [error description](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-rest-api/APIRequests_HTTPValidationErrors.html) in not helpful in this case.